# How to set the starting time and order on a ggplot x axis

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to order the below plot `x-axis` time from `04:00,05:00,06:00....,03:00`. Please find below my code and data sample

[image]

Code:

```
inds <- match('04:00', df1$time)
df1<-df1[c(inds:nrow(df1), 1:(inds - 1)), ]

plot<-ggplot(df1,aes(x=time,y=Percent,group=Season))+geom_line(aes(linetype=Season, color=Season), size=1) +scale_x_discrete(breaks = c( "04:00","05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00","13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00","22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00"), expand = c(0,0),  name= "Time (hours)")+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0, 0),  labels = scales::percent,name= "Seasonality")  +theme_bw()  
plot+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1,angle=90,family="Times", face="bold", size=12), axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12),strip.text = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
```

Sample data

```
df1<-structure(list(time=c ("00:00", "01:00","02:00","03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00",
                            "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00",
                             "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", "23:00"), 
                   Season = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                              "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                              "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), 
                   Total= c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,12,1,1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,12,9,10,12 ), 
                   Percent= c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10,0.12,0.1,0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10,0.10,0.2,0.9,0.10)  
                  ), row.names = c(NA,24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to manage the factor levels in the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(row_number() < match('04:00', time)) %>%
  mutate(time = factor(time, unique(time))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=time,y=Percent,group=Season) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Season, color=Season), size=1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, angle=90, family="Times",
                                   face="bold", size=12), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(family="Times", face="bold", size=12),
        strip.text = element_text(size=12, face="bold"))
```

[image]